# "merge" a raster data set on precipitation with a shapefile of administrative districts.

Tags: qgis

I'm currently using QGIS 1.8.0

I would like to "merge" a raster data set on precipitation with a shapefile of administrative districts.

Basically my the aim is to figure out the precipitation in different administrative areas. The data I have on precipitation is formatted in a lat/lon 0.5 grid. Each administrative district however intersects several of these 0.5x0.5 squares. How can I connect each administrative district to multiple corresponding 0.5x0.5 squares and then weigh the value of the squares that are only partially contained in the administrative district/ split up the squares that are divided between several districts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the QGIS [Zonal Statistics](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html) plugin.